# Elasticsearch relative time range query in Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have searched and searched but cannot find an answer for this.  I am new to using Elasticsearch with Python and trying to do a simple Python query against my Elasticsearch index which will return a count of the results matching a specific set of criteria in the past hour. I'm getting all the results back using the following (sanitized) code:

```
 hits = es.count(index='myindex-*',q=thing.rstrip() )
```

Simple enough right? So is there a way to include a relative time range in this query, or do I need to write some Python to figure out the times to insert as a time range?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, everything you need is a time-based key in your index and then query that key with:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "range" : {
            "<time_based_key>" : {
                "gte" : "now-1h"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To define your time-based key:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/<database>/<index>/_mapping?pretty -d '
{
    "<index>" : {
        "properties": {
            "<time_based_key>" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: OK that's helpful.  Two questions:  Can I use @timestamp as my time based key, and how does this translate into using count inside Python?

Comment: Yes, you can use whatever key you want, you just need to set it with a date (`datetime.now()` in Python?). Relatively to count, the dictionary returned by elasticsearch will contains a key called `hits` and inside the value of `hits` you will have another key called `total` meaning the number of results returned.

Comment: That got me where I needed to be.  Thanks!